# Missing ',' in line when Biopython reads a nexus tree

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython, phylogeny

I want to edit a tree that I got from **BEAST2** treeannotator in nexus-format.
Usually I use the module `Phylo` from **Biopython** for such work but `Phylo.read(r"filename.tree", "nexus")` gave me the next exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NexusError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [29], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 Phylo.read(r"filename.tree", "nexus")

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\Bio\Phylo\_io.py:60, in read(file, format, **kwargs)
     58 try:
     59     tree_gen = parse(file, format, **kwargs)
---> 60     tree = next(tree_gen)
     61 except StopIteration:
     62     raise ValueError("There are no trees in this file.") from None

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\Bio\Phylo\_io.py:49, in parse(file, format, **kwargs)
     34 """Parse a file iteratively, and yield each of the trees it contains.
     35 
     36 If a file only contains one tree, this still returns an iterable object that
   (...)
     46 
     47 """
     48 with File.as_handle(file) as fp:
---> 49     yield from getattr(supported_formats[format], "parse")(fp, **kwargs)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\Bio\Phylo\NexusIO.py:40, in parse(handle)
     32 def parse(handle):
     33     """Parse the trees in a Nexus file.
     34 
     35     Uses the old Nexus.Trees parser to extract the trees, converts them back to
   (...)
     38     eventually change Nexus to use the new NewickIO parser directly.)
     39     """
---> 40     nex = Nexus.Nexus(handle)
     42     # NB: Once Nexus.Trees is modified to use Tree.Newick objects, do this:
     43     # return iter(nex.trees)
     44     # Until then, convert the Nexus.Trees.Tree object hierarchy:
     45     def node2clade(nxtree, node):

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\Bio\Nexus\Nexus.py:668, in Nexus.__init__(self, input)
    665 self.options["gapmode"] = "missing"
    667 if input:
--> 668     self.read(input)
    669 else:
    670     self.read(DEFAULTNEXUS)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\Bio\Nexus\Nexus.py:718, in Nexus.read(self, input)
    716     break
    717 if title in KNOWN_NEXUS_BLOCKS:
--> 718     self._parse_nexus_block(title, contents)
    719 else:
    720     self._unknown_nexus_block(title, contents)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\Bio\Nexus\Nexus.py:759, in Nexus._parse_nexus_block(self, title, contents)
    757 for line in block.commandlines:
    758     try:
--> 759         getattr(self, "_" + line.command)(line.options)
    760     except AttributeError:
    761         raise NexusError("Unknown command: %s " % line.command) from None

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\Bio\Nexus\Nexus.py:1144, in Nexus._translate(self, options)
   1142         break
   1143     elif c != ",":
-> 1144         raise NexusError("Missing ',' in line %s." % options)
   1145 except NexusError:
   1146     raise

NexusError: Missing ',' in line 1 AB298157.1_2015_-7.9133750332192605_114.8086828279248, 2 AB298158.1_2007_-8.41698974207…
```

Using `Nexus.read(Nexus(), input=r"filename.tree")` gave the same result. Please could anyone help with this? I cannot understand the reason of this error because [nexus file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ex_dbdA6IdkRBU33qLuo0sOXty2k3JHu/view?usp=sharing) looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that **Biopython** cannot read nexus trees with links, constituent from translations & a newick tree. So it is required previously to convert this to the form with full names into the tree (as hereinbelow).

```
Begin
    tree TREE1 = (((your,tree),(in,(the, newick))),format);
End;
```

P.S. It is allowed in the **newick** format to surround the label with quotes, & some programmes or scripts add them to those names that have ambiguous characters. But it can lead to exceptions during the following phylogenetic analysis, for instance, in **BEAST**. I wish you would be careful with this.